# Making a textField inside a movie clip display specific text after mouse click in actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

first of all let me clarify that I've been working with AS3 only for a couple of days. My project consists of a google map of a street which acts as a menu where the buttons are labels floating over some of the houses. The idea is that when you click on certain house a module of specific info spreads. That info would be textual and some photos. My intention is to have that module as a movie clip template that I create just once and would fill up dynamically with the info related with each clicked house. It's a long way to get to that and I still have to figure how to do it. But I'm starting with this little thing:
I want that when I click on certain button it tells a dynamic text field inside the movie clip to display the house address which acts as a tittle for the card where the info is displayed. I'm experimenting with currentTarget but despite not getting any errors the code is just not working. Here's my code:

```
z5990_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,setTittle);
function setTittle(event:MouseEvent)
  { 
    var target = event.currentTarget;
    var tittle = houseCard_mc.tittle_txt;
    tittle.text=String(target);

     }
```

Please note that my learning consists basically of reading and asking forums and lots of trail and error. Thanks for taking time to read this and help me.

Comment: is z5990_btn a MovieClip? And what do you want to set inside the textField?

Comment: Try `function setTittle(event:MouseEvent) { houseCard_mc.tittle_txt.text = "hello world"; }`... does that work? That snippet is assuming that the MC (`houseCard_mc`) contains a textField inside it with given **instance name** of _tittle_txt_ so it will give you access to update the text

Comment: Well I tried that code with no luck. Same results as before. No errors but not working either. I tried many things with movie clip instances and text fields and nothing changed. I don't know what is happening. Thanks VC.

Answer (score 0):

Trace `tittle` to make sure it's actual `TextField`:

```
//...
var tittle = houseCard_mc.tittle_txt;
trace("tittle is:", tittle, "currentText:", tittle.text);
tittle.text=String(target);
```

you should see this in output:

> tittle is: [object TextField] currentText: foo

if it's not a `TextField` object but `MovieClip` then you will see this.

> tittle is: [object  MovieClip] currentText: undefined

Than means that you are creating new `text` field in your `tittle` MovieClip with string content, which of course does nothing.

All you need to do is read for instance [THIS EXAMPLE](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7d7d.html)

Comment: Thank you Pawel, I'll retry with this method sometime in the near future. I had to take a more effective approach because of the deadline I have with this project. This one however is sort of a demo of a much bigger project. I'll need more scripting on that one to make my life easier so I'll try this and get back to you.

Comment: You don't need to replicate the example. This is just to show you how you can organize your project. I you trace MovieClip instead of text field you just accesing the wrong object. You just need to understand display list to know were to put your TextField instance and how to access it. If you don't have time for complex examples maybe just read [Traversing the display list](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e26.html)